# define custom fields for systemd-journald

Tags: systemd, rsyslog, syslog, journald

The [doc](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/systemd.journal-fields.7.html) states, it may be possible to define new fields by applications.

What does it mean? Can one define arbitrary fields or are only those possible listed in the [doc](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/systemd.journal-fields.7.html) USER JOURNAL FIELDS?

If arbitrary fields are possible, how to define them then?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Arbitrary fields are definitely possible.
You don't see them when `$ journalctl`ing by plain text.
You see your fields best by `$ journalctl -ar -o json-pretty`.

Which means

- showing all fields regardless whether they have non-printable characters in [-a]
- in reverse order - latest messages first [-r]
- by printing in json format [-o]